# Ractive JS and updating MathJax with LaTeX input?

Tags: javascript, mathjax, ractivejs

I am trying to make [ractive.js](http://www.ractivejs.org/) dynamically update [MathJax](http://www.mathjax.org/).

Now I know you can trigger a MathJax reload with:

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue.Push(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
```

So I've bound this to the observe callback:

```
  ractive.observe('input', function (input) {
    ractive.set('output', input * 2);
    MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub]);
  });
```

But when I try to render the MathJax with `\begin{equation} {{output}} \end{equation}`
it remains at its initial value.

**[testcase](http://files.joelkuiper.eu/f/commit/8f64bd2/blog/org-reactive-literate/reactive-literate.html)**

The odd thing is that does get the initial value, just not the updates.

Any thoughts?

*EDIT:* It does seem to add a whole bunch of nested `MathJax_MathContainer` elements, one for each call it appears.

---

[JsFiddle demo with Peter Krautzberger's suggestion](https://jsfiddle.net/dyc0xt4y/) -- still does not seem to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The thing is that MathJax removes the elements from the DOM so Ractive can no longer update them. This can be solved by instead of using the MathJax searches (e.g. `$$`) wrapping the LaTeX in a `<script type="math/tex; mode=display" id="foo">` element. This will prevent the replacement since MathJax can handle the script element internally.

Now you can observe the variables and trigger the repaint with `MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset",MathJax.Hub, "foo"]);`

Many thanks to [Peter Krautzberger](https://twitter.com/pkrautz/statuses/403620011853742081) for the suggestion / solution.

Comment: Did you not run into trouble nesting a script tag for MathJax within the script tag for Ractive templates?

Comment: I got Ractive to use the `template` tag instead but it still doesn't work, would you be willing to post working code for your example? Here's my non-working code: https://jsfiddle.net/qpk70h1t/

Answer (score 1):

@wrongusername I don't have any experience with Ractive and I only worked with MathJax about 3 years back but I have tried `Reprocess` instead of `Typeset`, it worked. I think you should use `Reprocess` because your input changed. From the [documentation](http://mathjax.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api/hub.html#Reprocess), it says

> Removes any typeset mathematics from the document or DOM element (or
>   elements if it is an array of elements), and then processes the
>   mathematics again, re-typesetting everything.

See the updated [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qpk70h1t/6/) here.

You just need to replace

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Typeset", MathJax.Hub, "foo"]);
```

with

```
MathJax.Hub.Queue(["Reprocess", MathJax.Hub, "foo"]);
```

Hope it helps.